# Android Dictionary upgrade

Tags: java, android, dictionary

Can someone guide me to the code in the git from where all apps in android can add words to default dictionary.

I thought it would be easy because all edit box are capable of adding words to android default dictionary. But the solutions I found are using the ndk and are not working on HTC devices.

Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The [UserDictionary](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.html) is part of the Android SDK and can be used to add words for predictive texting.

Comment: Can we add words containing special symbol from UTF16.